# Make a POST Json request using Retrofit just like in jQuery ajax

Tags: java, android, jquery, ajax, retrofit2

I am using jQuery ajax from my website to do POST requests to our server, so it can send me json data I can use.
All the ajax request I am making look like this:

```
getLanguages(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        cache: false,
        url: 'https://www.someurl.com/fc.php',
        data: {
            mode: 'language'
        },
        success: callback
    });
},

requestCountries(phone, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        cache: false,
        url: 'https://www.someurl.com/fc.php',
        data: {
            mode: 'country',
            phone: phone,
            langId: myStorage.getLanguage()
        },
        success: callback
    });
},
```

The only different things are in the `data` parameter, so that's whats important.
Now I am trying to achieve the same thing in Android using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), but I can't understand anything, as it have basically no documentation, so here's what I managed to build from user examples from here and there:

```
    String url = "https://www.someurl.com";
    JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
    obj.addProperty("mode", "language");
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    MyRetrofit myretro = retrofit.create(MyRetrofit.class);
    myretro.getLanguage(obj, new Callback<Language>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Language> call, Response<Language> response) {
            Log.d("response", "response");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Language> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("response", "response");
        }
    });
```

and this is MyRetrofit.java

```
public interface MyRetrofit {

    @POST("/fc.php")
    Call<Void> getLanguage(@Body JsonObject json, Callback<Language> callback);
}
```

Here is the Language class

```
public class Language {
    private String langId;
    private String langName;
    private String langIcon;
}
```

When I run the code it crashed with this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)
```

How can I achieve what I need, any help, explanations or recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: if you are using retrofit2 why do you have  `Callback<JSONObject> callBack` in `getUser`?. check this https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

Comment: @Raghunandan ok I updated my code, changed the jsonobject and other parameters to be from Retrofit or Gson

Comment: you still have not updated fully with version2 in getLanguage you still have , `Callback<Language> callback`

Comment: no, the Callback is from import retrofit2.Callback;

Comment: what is this enqueue method and what is this Repo object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147504/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-sartheris-stormhammer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
 // you do not need callback parameter here
 public interface MyRetrofit {

@POST("fc.php")
Call<Language> getLanguage(@Body JsonObject json);
  }
```

Also make sure your baseurl is

```
https://www.someurl.com/
```

The end point is fc.php

```
  @POST("fc.php")
```

For example assume you have end point as post/user you would have @POST("post/user") and your baseurl would be https://www.someurl.com/. Also put your baseurl is some utility file as constants and also define your end points so that you can easily change them in one place and refer it wherever you need.

Then

```
Call<Language> call = myretro.getLanguage(obj);
// for asynchronous call
call.enqueue(new Callback<Language>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Language> call, Response<Language> response) {
        Log.d("response", "response");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Language> call, Throwable t) {
        t.printstackTrace();

    }
});
```

Tip : You can use pojo and convert them to json using gson which is what you get with the gsonconverter.

Edit: For Debugging you can log the request and response

```
   OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

            Request originalRequest = chain.request(); //Current Request

            Response response = chain.proceed(originalRequest); //Get response of the request

            //I am logging the response body in debug mode. When I do this I consume the response (OKHttp only lets you do this once) so i have re-build a new one using the cached body
            String bodyString = response.body().string();

            Log.i("NetworkModule", String.format("Sending request %s with headers %s ", originalRequest.url(), originalRequest.headers()));
            Log.i("", (String.format("Got response HTTP %s %s \n\n with body %s \n\n with headers %s ", response.code(), response.message(), bodyString, response.headers())));

            response = response.newBuilder().body(
                    ResponseBody.create(response.body().contentType(), bodyString))
                    .build();

            return response;
        }
    }).connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
```

Then

```
   Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))          
            .build();
```

Comment: not working, I am getting error on the Call<Language> call = myretro.getLanguage(obj); because it needs another parameter for the callback, and when I add it, it still crashes with this error No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)

Comment: remove the callback from the parameter. that was a copy paste mistake. dam. let me edit the post

Comment: yes now it does not crashes, though the server guy told me that I am not sending him anything, the JsonObject I am putting mode language in, is nowhere to be seen in POST in the server... any idea on that? If not, I'll mark as solved, since it doesn't crash now

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer you log your post request and response with okhttp interceptors then see what your are sending and what is the response.

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer if you do not know to log i can post that code as well

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Call<Void> getUser(....)
```

Comment: Now I am getting - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create @Body converter for class org.json.JSONObject (parameter #1), Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate RequestBody converter for class org.json.JSONObject.

Comment: will try to add Gson now

Comment: yes try adding 
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())

Comment: ok now I am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)